# NativeScript WebView canvas support?

Tags: canvas, nativescript

We installed the nativescript-canvas-interface plugin so that we can display something on our app that uses the  tag.  That tag works in a regular browser but not in our NativeScript app.  There's no error to indicate why.  Even when we use demos provided by that plugin we don't see anything rendered in the canvas.

Is there something special that needs to be done to get that tag to work or does NativeScript not fully support that tag yet?

Comment: which version of {NS} are you using?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya `tns --version` says 4.2.4

Comment: Forgot to ask is it VanillaJS or Angular project and which platform are you testing right now? Android or ios?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I'm using VanillaJS with both iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

The demo app seems to work just fine on my end, but of course I had to update the project in align with latest typescript template so it could work with CLI 5.x and Xcode 10.

[image: iPad Simulator]

Comment: If still have issues, try my [fork here](https://github.com/manojdcoder/nativescript-canvas-interface-demo)

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  If you want to enable Issues in your GitHub repo I can provide the output.

Comment: As I mentioned already, I had configured the project for the latest version of CLI and Runtime (v5.0). Upgrade your CLI, clone the repo, and just `tns run ios` should work.

Comment: I did.  tns --version = 5.0.1

Comment: I have enabled issues.